# Using PowerShell to list user with access to a shared or user mailbox

Tags: powershell, exchange

I would like to export a list of shared and user mailboxes and the staff which have access to those mailboxes.

I know I can use the following to get this information by user but since there are fewer shared mailboxes and some user mailboxes in which multiple people have access the list should be shorter.

I would like to include all the shared mailboxes and some user mailboxes to which staff have access and export to a list that can be sorted in Excel.

```
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox,SharedMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission -User Sampled | Export-csv c:\Temp\MailboxAccess.txt
```

Comment: Did you also use AD groups here? Means is an AD group having access to your shared mailbox? Then you need to parse also groups...